# How to implement an async generator to stream with node Readable stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I want to do something like this

```
const { Readable } = require("stream");

function generatorToStream(generator) {
  return new Readable({
    read() {
      (async () => {
        for await (const result of generator()) {
          if (result.done) {
            this.push(null);
          } else {
            this.push(result.value);
          }
        }
      })();
    }
  });
}

generatorToStream(async function*() {
  const msg1 = await new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve("ola amigao"), 2000)
  );
  yield msg1;
  const msg2 = await new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve("ola amigao"), 2000)
  );
  yield msg2;

  const msg3 = await new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve("ola amigao"), 2000)
  );
  yield msg3;
}).pipe(process.stdout);
```

but it's not working, the end event has never been called and i haven't received any data on my terminal.

Any solution or tips on how to implement it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, especially unhandled promise rejections? Try appending `.catch(console.error)` to your IIAFE.

Comment: IIRC the `result` won't be an iteration record when you are using `for await of`, but the value itself. When the generator is done, the loop just ends.

Comment: An `async function` with `await` called separately for each Promise is just like a generator. Is it even possible to combine them?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of [Scramjet](https://www.scramjet.org/), a functional stream processing framework that may be an easy solution for you.

If you're ok with adding a total of just 3 dependencies to your project then it couldn't be easier:

```
const {StringStream} = require("scramjet");

StringStream.from(async function* () {
    yield await something();
    ...
});
```

If you want to implement this on your own, take a look at the source code in [DataStream line 112](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet-core/blob/master/lib/data-stream.js#L112) - it should be fairly easy to implement. In general you'd need to implement something like this:

```
function generatorToStream(gen) {
    // obtain an iterator
    const iter = await gen();
    // create your output
    const out = new Passthrough();

    // this IIFE will do all the work
    (async () => {
        let done = false;
        for await (let chunk of iter) {
            // if write returns true, continue, otherwise wait until out is drained.
            if (!out.write(chunk)) await new Promise((res, rej) => this.once("drain", res);
        }
    })()
        // handle errors by pushing them to the stream for example
        .catch(e => out.emit('error', e));

    // return the output stream
    return out;
}
```

The above example is more or less what's happening in scramjet - there's a little more optimization there on keeping less event handlers and so on, but the above should work well in a simple case.

Comment: Kudos for disclaiming that you are the author of the lib before anything else, concealed self advertisement is very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Very basic working sample below:

```
import { Readable } from 'stream';

const generator = async function* () {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
};

const myReadableStream = Readable.from(generator());
myReadableStream.on('data', (data) => console.log(data));
```